# Help creating a simple function

Tags: functions, function-construction

Can someone help me to create a function. The truth I'm new in Mathematica and I don't understand well the way functions work in I. I need a function that animate some rectangles according to a curve that I introduce as a vector depending on time. I already did this, but I don't want to do for every curve. The animation that I have is the next:

```
{Animate[Graphics[  {{Red, 
     Polygon[{{0 , 0}, {1, 0}, {Flatten[a[t]][[1]] + 1, 
        1}, {Flatten[a[t]][[1]], 1}}]}, {Blue, 
     Polygon[{{Flatten[a[t]][[1]] + 1, 1}, {Flatten[a[t]][[1]], 
        1}, {Flatten[a[t]][[2]], 2}, {Flatten[a[t]][[2]] + 1, 2}}]},
    {Green, 
     Polygon[{{Flatten[a[t]][[2]] + 1, 2}, {Flatten[a[t]][[2]], 
        2}, {Flatten[a[t]][[3]], 3}, {Flatten[a[t]][[3]] + 1, 3}}]},
    {Black, 
     Polygon[{{Flatten[a[t]][[3]] + 1, 3}, {Flatten[a[t]][[3]], 
        3}, {Flatten[a[t]][[4]], 4}, {Flatten[a[t]][[4]] + 1, 4}}]},
    {Orange, 
     Polygon[{{Flatten[a[t]][[4]] + 1, 4}, {Flatten[a[t]][[4]], 
        4}, {Flatten[a[t]][[5]], 5}, {Flatten[a[t]][[5]] + 1, 5}}]},
    {Blue, 
     Polygon[{{Flatten[a[t]][[5]] + 1, 5}, {Flatten[a[t]][[5]], 
        5}, {Flatten[a[t]][[6]], 6}, {Flatten[a[t]][[6]] + 1, 6}}]},
    {Pink, 
     Polygon[{{Flatten[a[t]][[6]], 6}, {Flatten[a[t]][[6]] + 1, 
        6}, {Flatten[a[t]][[7]] + 1, 7}, {Flatten[a[t]][[7]], 7}}]}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 8}}]   , {t , 0, 2 Pi} , 
  AnimationRunning -> False]}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to transform this code into a function so I just call the function with a different vector and get the animation?

Comment: Your code won't work without some definition for `a[t]`.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this?, in other languages I could use a block like this and then call the function with the vector that I want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like

```
colors = {Red, Blue, Green, Black, Orange, Blue, Pink};
aA = Sin[t] RandomInteger[{1, 7}, {7}];

table = Table[{{aA[[k]] + 1, k}, {aA[[k]], k},
               {aA[[k + 1]], k + 1}, {aA[[k + 1]] + 1, k + 1}}, {k, 1, 6}];
polygons = Polygon /@ Prepend[table, Join[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, table[[1, ;; 2]]]];

Animate[Evaluate@ Graphics[Thread[{colors, polygons}], PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {0, 8}}], 
       {t, 0, 2 Pi}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Change `aC` to

```
aC = Cos[t^2/2] RandomInteger[{1, 7}, {7}];
```

and `{t, 0, 2 Pi}` to `{t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}` to get
[image]